# WCF Time changes on server causes disconnect

Tags: wcf, time

while changing the time on my server (which hosts a WCF application) I noticed all clients would be disconnected. I do understand why this would happen, they get disconnected because of the timeout, since if we set the time an hour later the reliable session which is set to 15 second timeout will be long expired. Funny thing though, if you set it back by whatever amount of time, it won't lose the connection but setting it forward by anything more than 15 seconds cause the problem.

The thing is, can we prevent the clients from disconnecting when the server time changes, because I find this behaviour quite strange and having all clients disconnect is a real problem.

We need to adjust the server time because it will get out of sync, it is not something we can do often since we need to go to the physical location (which is the customer's location). The servers are placed in highly secured areas and they are not able to access an (or any) external server because of security reasons, we need the entire network to be inaccessible from the outside.
Installing our own time server will often have the same problem, it'll get out of sync and the solutions that stay within an acceptable margin are often too expensive.

Comment: Why is the server time changing by an hour? If it's because of daylight saving that should be handled by the OS option to honour daylight saving and won't affect connections.

Comment: @ChrisF When we need to adjust the time because the server (or clients) are out of sync.

Comment: Why are they out of sync? You should be syncing machines to an external time server. If you do this then they should never be out of sync by more than a few seconds.

Comment: @ChrisF we cannot connect to an external server, and setting up our own internal server would still have the same problems, eventually they will run out of sync, and the solutions that do this in an acceptable margin are often too expensive.

Comment: Please can you update your question to include this new and highly relevant information - including **why** you can't connect to an external time server. Without it you won't get an answer that actually addresses your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a binding to not include a timestamp in the SOAP. Use a CustomBinding for that.

Here's example code of a project, I'm curious if it worked! Note that this code also sets SOAP version 1.1, you might to change/remove that.

```
private Binding CreateBindingSoap11_NoTimeStamp()
{
    BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);

    BindingElementCollection elements = httpBinding.CreateBindingElements();
    elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().IncludeTimestamp = false;
    elements.Find<TextMessageEncodingBindingElement>().MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11;

    CustomBinding newBinding = new CustomBinding(elements);

    return newBinding;
}
```

It also works with NetTcpBinding of course